# show informations section in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am new in opencart.I have created new theme and copy the following code from footer file to header file. I have used following code to display information section in mytheme's header.

">

Problem is that it shows error ": Undefined variable: informations". please help me regarding this. what causes that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the information section as in the information pages that Opencart has within the admin section, or you want to place information in the header?  Can you show an example of your header?

Comment: the following code is using: <?php echo $text_information; ?></h3>
      <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to load the information in the controller for the header `catalog/controller/common/header.php` from the footer `catalog/controller/common/footer.php`

```
    $this->load->model('catalog/information');

    $this->data['informations'] = array();

    foreach ($this->model_catalog_information->getInformations() as $result) {
        if ($result['bottom']) {
            $this->data['informations'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'href'  => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $result['information_id'])
            );
        }
    }
```

Once you do that you should be good to go